# NodeJS app crashes after several requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

This is my most annoying problems of all time, i have a simple get request handler in my nodejs app

```
router.get('/api/docs/fetch', async (req,res) => {
    try{
       let docs = await Doc.find({public: true}).limit(5);
       const docsToSend = docs.filter(doc => new Date(doc.expires) < new Date().getTime());
       return res.status(200).send({
           docs: docsToSend
       })
    }catch(err){
        return res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message
        })
    }
})
```

and after several request my application crashes (it is random number, for now it is 22), i've faced this issue so many  times but i do not know it was solved somehow (mostly i had `JSON.stringify(array)` in my code and removing stringify solved problem) but i do not have any clue for this, i have tried performing request with postman and last request delays for infinity, i have also tried it with axios and javascript's native fetch method but i've got same result. what is problem and how can i fix it?

Comment: try to use `res.json` instead of `res.send`

Comment: and remove the `return` statement, for now, I think it may that what happens that the res.send executed out of your try-catch blocks

Comment: give me a minute

Comment: it is not working

Comment: can you log the caught error? or share with us the log messages from the crashed node process?

Comment: there is no error messages, it just does not work. i think it is network error

Comment: can you log the error in uncaughtException event, process.on('uncaughtException', err => { console.log(err)}). so it will be helpful to understand whats its happening exactly

Comment: one sec please!

Comment: I really think the problem is the new Date(doc.expires) < new Date().getTime() portion, the left hand side is an object, and right hand side is a number. So how are you comparing both? and what happens if doc.expires is null or undefined? I think the problem lies there. @iLiA 

Can you console log every `doc.expires` in the filter function? and check when it is being crashed. the below answer solves the problem using Mongo query but doesn't fix the syntax error(if it is even here) in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be due to **scope** issues:

> Try the following:

```js
const getDocs = async () => {
  return Doc
    .find({
      public: true,
      expires: {
        $gte: new Date().getTime()
      }
    })
    .limit(5);
}

router.get('/api/docs/fetch', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const docs = await getDocs()
    res.status(200).json({ docs })
  } catch ({ message }) {
    res.status(500).json({ message })
  }
})
```

Comment: can you explain little more related to the scope issues, so it will be helpful to understand the problem in a better way

Comment: sure, so for our friend issues here, when he returned ` return res.status(200).send({ docs: docsToSend       })`  the express framework will try to detect the argument type and if its JSON will change the content type to match and convert to stringified object and all that happens outside the controller scope (remains un-catched)

Comment: little confused, so the basic concept is whatever you write inside try catch if something fails you will be able to catch it thats the basic concept of try catch, but how this one works outside, any docs or articles related to this

Comment: when you return sth its goes to the caller fo that's returned function, and if the returned value is a function and gets called it's now outside the function call

Comment: @EslamAbuHugair Yeah, it works (i've performed 50 request) and it works, but as DILEEP THOMAS said, i am a little confused how it works

Comment: should i move every DB query outside router ?

Comment: and also please link any resource about this

Comment: @iLiA No no need to move the Db, but as best practice, you can move any direct interaction with DB to services folder, and keep your controller logic clean, so you can move faster and cleaner

Comment: @EslamAbuHugair Instead of writing a seperate function,  if i put a await infront of await docs.filter(doc => new ... will it solve the issue. Or we need to seperate the function outside. How this works. Still i didnt get the entire thing. Trying to solve a problem is stackoverflow is basically learning more :) so hoping for a detailed info

Comment: I just looked through whole express documentation and dying to see the article about this scope issues

Comment: it's not an express issue it a javascript convention

Comment: as dileep said i just removed filter method and it started working perfectly, i do not know why did it work for first 22 request tho

Comment: @EslamAbuHugair please provide me some article about this

Comment: I really think the problem is the `new Date(doc.expires) < new Date().getTime()` portion, the left hand side is an `object`, and right hand side is a `number`. So how are you comparing both? and what happens if `doc.expires` is `null` or `undefined`? I think the problem lies there. @iLiA

Comment: if so, the try-catch block would catch the error @AritraChakraborty .

Comment: @iLiA I'll one the first break I have, I'll also provide you with a demo snippet ^_^

Comment: Oh my god, @AritraChakraborty You are right!!!!, i think thats a result for writing code late night, and @Eslam Abu Hugair, i think problem is with filter, because in your example you used mongodb's comparasion query operator and excluded filter from code and that was reason why code started working. doc.expires is a Date type so i should have used `.getTime()` and when i did it started working, but without adding getTime and using Eslams method (removing $gte and using filter instead) it still worked. and i am very confused about it. i can not find any explanation for this.

Comment: also why did not catch caught this problem?

Comment: Eslam i would still like convention you mentioned